# Loading an image from a NES CHR file (i.e., a binary file) and showing on a Windows Form

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# form that reads graphics from a binary file and allows me to create maps with it. I'm having trouble trying to display an image on the form based on the bytes in the binary file. This binary file stores a bunch of 8x8 pixel images and each row of this image is stored in two different bytes, which I have to do some processing on. After reading all the bytes, I need to get palette data based on these bytes and then I can finally get my image colored properly.

I won't get into details of how the image processing works, since I think I can do that by myself (unless someone is curious, then I can explain in more detail - I'm basically reading a CHR file that contains patterns for a NES game and displaying a tile using the NES palette). By the end of all this processing, I have the RGB values for each pixel of the image stored as a byte array. My problem is that I don't know how to convert this byte array into a 8x8 image.

So for example, suppose I have a 8x8 tile that is just a red tile. By the end of the processing, this tile would be represented by an array like this (each pixel uses 3 bytes: byte 1 = R, byte 2 = G, byte 3 = B):

```
byte[] tilecolors = {255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0, }
```

So, binary file has a bunch of these images stored in it as bytes and I want to do is transform those bytes into 8x8 images that will be displayed in an app (probably inside a picturebox, since I want the app user to use these tiles to create maps and stuff).

I tried using a function I saw on another website that reads loads an image from bytes using MemoryStream, but I get a "Parameter is not valid" error. This is the function I tried:

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
   Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
   return returnImage;
}
```

#### EDIT:

I got it to work by following @ckuri 's suggestion. After I calculate the RGB colors from reading the binary file, I can use the Bitmap class's SetPixel method to draw the image.

Comment: `Image.FromStream` expects a proper proper bitmap format like Windows bitmaps including the header, PNGs, …. tile colors just seem to be the RGB values, but is missing the header which contains the image dimensions and other data. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format for more details.

Comment: After filling stream you need to set position of stream to zero before reading : ms.Position = 0;

Comment: Do I necessarily need to create a proper bitmap with header and everything if I want to display those pixels on the form? I was wondering if there was a way to keep things simple, because the input and output of this app will only be binary files, I'll never have to deal with images. I just want to display these bytes as images on the form so I can use them to create maps (which will be just a bunch of bytes in the end)

Comment: @jdweng The position is already 0 when you initialize the MemoryStream via the constructor.

Comment: @zanto If you want to load an image via a stream it must be a proper bitmap. How else would the Image class know which format the image data has w.r.t. image dimensions, bit depth, compression, and so on? Another simpler approach would be to instantiate a Bitmap class (which inherits from the Image class) and use its SetPixel method to fill it. Usually it’s somewhat slow, but it wouldn’t matter for 8x8 images.

Comment: @ckuri : But after you fill the ms it is at the last position.  When you then read you read nothing since you are at the end of the stream.

Comment: @jdweng But not when you do it like OP has done: `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);`. The stream will still be at position 0.

Comment: Really?  What happens if you want to add more data at end of stream?

Comment: Your suggestion worked, @ckuri! Thank you very much!